# In the reference frame of an observer an arbitrarily large distance away, can event horizons form in finite time?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, observers, event-horizon

There are similar questions answered already but the answers disagree. I understand that simultaneity/time is local in GR and that in a given region of space, an event horizon and singularity can form in finite proper time for a local observer. For a distant observer, will the event horizon form in a finite amount of their proper time? And if not, can an observer travel from a frame in which the event horizon and/or singularity has formed to one in which it hasn't?

Thanks.

Comment: This can't be answered because in curved spacetime, reference frames only have local meaning.